# What is confidence in JSON response?

Tags: python, android, json

I am doing a project on some image processing in python, and I wonder what does confidence=1 or some other number represent when I get JSON response?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: from where do you get that response?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [quality factor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Quality_values) in an `accept` header? A value of `1` in that case just prioritizes the desired type, but if there are other types with the same value, it is basically up to the server to choose. Basically, the server isn’t required to send a JSON response.